# Change 3D background to black in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I'm having trouble changing the background of my 3d graph to black. This is my current code. When I do set facecolor to black, it changes the inside of the graph to be grey, which is not what I want.

[image]

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.grid(False)
ax.xaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('b')
ax.yaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('b')
ax.zaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('b')

# plt.gca().patch.set_facecolor('white')
# plt.axis('On')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('black')

ax.scatter(xs = Z['PC1'], ys = Z['PC2'], zs = Z['PC3'], c = Z['color'], s = 90, depthshade= False)
ax.set(title = 'test', xlabel = 'PC1', ylabel = 'PC2', zlabel = 'PC3')
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to keep the wireframe axis you can do

```
ax.w_xaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.w_yaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.w_zaxis.pane.fill = False
```

Here's a complete example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
x, y, z = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 250))

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=np.random.randn(250))

fig.set_facecolor('black')
ax.set_facecolor('black') 
ax.grid(False) 
ax.w_xaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.w_yaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.w_zaxis.pane.fill = False
```

[image]

Or you can hide them altogether with

```
ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
ax.w_yaxis.set_pane_color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
ax.w_zaxis.set_pane_color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

Complete example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
x, y, z = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 250))

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=np.random.randn(250))

fig.set_facecolor('black')
ax.set_facecolor('black')
ax.grid(False)
ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
ax.w_yaxis.set_pane_color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
ax.w_zaxis.set_pane_color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use Matplotlib's dark background [style sheet](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/style_sheets/dark_background.html), which uses white for elements that are typically black (text, borders, etc). It also works for 3D plots.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.style.use('dark_background')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

L = 6
x = np.linspace(0, L)
ncolors = len(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])
shift = np.linspace(0, L, ncolors, endpoint=False)
for s in shift:
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(x + s), 'o-')
ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax.set_title("'dark_background' style sheet")

plt.show()
```

Comment: plt.style.use will set the style for all the plots in the jupyter notebook, I would like to do this only for a particular plot

Comment: then reset the style to default. `plt.style.use('default')`